Jenkins is not able to connet with prometheus using localhost metrics
enter image description here
im trying to connet jenkins using localhost:8080 with prometheus but it showing DOWN state with OOPS Not Found! pageenter image description here
Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
- "first_rules.yml"
- "second_rules.yml"
A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
Scrape Prometheus itself

job_name: "prometheus"
static_configs:

targets: ["localhost:9090"]



Scrape Jenkins metrics

job_name: "jenkins"
metrics_path: "/metrics"  # Ensure this is correct for Jenkins metrics
static_configs:

targets: ["localhost:8080"]
labels:
job: "jenkins"




Are you using the Prometheus metrics plugin? If so, try scraping from the $JENKINS_URL/prometheus/ endpoint and see if you get results. As for the /metrics/ endpoint, are you using authentication in your Jenkins server? If so, go to $JENKINS_URL/metrics/currentUser/ and make sure that your user has access to metrics.
